# how to change the content size of a uipopoverpresentation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to load a view controller using popoverpresentation controller.But the size always remains a constant. how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this method

```
-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
   return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```